# Haskell : Non-Exhaustive Pattern In Function Prevents Another Function From Executing Even Though Its Not Used

Tags: parsing, haskell, eval

I'm trying to implement `car, cdr, and cons` functionality into a toy language I'm writing however when I try to execute my `car` function through `main`, I get the following error:

```
./parser "car [1 2 3]"
parser: parser.hs:(48,27)-(55,45): Non-exhaustive patterns in case
```

The function on lines 48-55 is the following:

```
parseOp :: Parser HVal
parseOp = (many1 letter <|> string "+" <|> string "-" <|> string "*" <|> string "/" <|> string "%" <|> string "&&" <|> string "||") >>= 
      (\x -> return $ case x of
                "&&" -> Op And
                "||" -> Op Or
                "+" -> Op Add
                "-" -> Op Sub
                "*" -> Op Mult
                "/" -> Op Div
                "%" -> Op Mod)
```

I'm really unsure why the error message points to this function because it has nothing to do with the list functionality. The `car` function is working however because I was able to successfully execute it through `GHCI`. I know my problem is due to parsing but I don't see where it is. The following are the functions that relate to lists. I can't see from them how they are influenced by `parseOp`.

```
data HVal = Number Integer
          | String String
          | Boolean Bool
          | List [HVal]
          | Op Op
          | Expr Op HVal HVal
          | Car [HVal]
           deriving (Read)

car :: [HVal] -> HVal
car xs = head xs


parseListFunctions :: Parser HVal
parseListFunctions = do
            _ <- string "car "
            _ <- char '['
            x <- parseList
            _ <- char ']'
            return $ Car [x]
            

parseExpr :: Parser HVal
parseExpr =  parseNumber
         <|> parseOp
         <|> parseBool
     <|> parseListFunctions 
         <|> do
        _ <- char '['
                x <- parseList
                _ <- char ']'
                return x
         <|> do
            _ <- char '('
            x <- parseExpression
                _ <- char ')'
                return x

eval :: HVal -> HVal
eval val@(Number _) = val
eval val@(String _) = val
eval val@(Boolean _) = val
eval val@(List _) = val -- Look at list eval NOT WORKING
eval val@(Op _) = val
eval (Expr op x y) = eval $ evalExpr (eval x) op (eval y)
eval (Car xs) = eval $ car xs
```

The removal of `many1 letter` in `parseOp` transfers the same error to the following function `parseBool`:

```
parseBool :: Parser HVal
parseBool = many1 letter >>= (\x -> return $ case x of
                                               "True" -> Boolean True
                                               "False" -> Boolean False)
```

Comment: `x` is a `String`; there are *many* more `String` values than the ones that the parser matches. At the type level, the `case` statement doesn't know that the parser will only ever produce certain `String` values.

Comment: Also, you haven't specified what to return if `many1 letter` matches.

Comment: Isn't the `many1 letter` bound to the `x` in the lambda function of `parseOp` which then returns an operator ? Would you able to explain your first statement, I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Your parser matches many letters, or one of the following strings. Whichever matches *first* is what gets bound to `x` in the following lambda expression. For example, if you match `&&`, you'll return `Op Mod`. But what if you match the string `foo`?

Comment: Perhaps you want `many1 letter <|> ((string "+" <|> ... <|> string "||") >>= \x -> case x of ...)` instead?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to remove the `many1 letter` from `parseOp` such that I can avoid the pattern matching of undesirable strings like `foo`?

Comment: Removing it actually transfers the error message to my function `parseBoolean` instead of `parseOp` strangely enough. I'll add that function into an edit.

Comment: Aside, it would help to structure your parsers like `(Op Add <$ string "+") <|> (Op Sub <$ string "-") <|> (Op Mult <$ String "*") <|> …` and `(Boolean True <$ string "True") <|> (Boolean False <$ string "False")`, where each subparser returns a parsed value *immediately* instead of passing a string to a `case` that may fail. In particular, your Boolean parser currently will consume any variable name, then throw an exception when it’s neither `"True"` nor `"False"`; the form I suggest will produce a clearer parse failure. You can also use `asum [a, b, c, …]` instead of `a <|> b <|> c <|> …`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write

```
parseExpr = ... <|> parseOp <|> ... <|> parseListFunctions <|> ...
```

and so

```
car ...
```

is passed to `parseOp` first, then `parseListFunctions`. The `parseOp` parser succeeds in the

```
many1 letter
```

branch, and so in the `\x -> return $ case x of ...`, `x` is bound to `"car"`. Because `parseOp` succeeds (and returns an error value with an embedded, not-yet-evaluated inexhaustive case error!), `parseListFunctions` is never tried.

You will need to modify your grammar to reduce the ambiguity in it, so that these conflicts where multiple branches may match do not arise.

Comment: That makes perfect sense looking at it now!